# SELECT query returning exception in C# method

Tags: c#, sql, npgsql

I'm newbie in C# and Npgsql and I'm trying to make a search in a certain table but I'm getting an exception.

```
public User Login(Account c)
{
    User usr = new User();
    using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(strConnection))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand();
            command.Connection = con;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM public.user WHERE c_id IN (SELECT id FROM public.account WHERE email=@Email AND password=@Password)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", c.Email);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", c.Password);
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                usr.Name = dr["name"].ToString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }    
    return usr;
}
```

Bellow the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No row is available'

I did the same thing but using PgAdmin4, and i've got one line. Exactly what i want to get.

```
SELECT name FROM public.user WHERE c_id IN (SELECT id FROM public.account WHERE email='user05@gmail.com' AND password='user05');
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Use a profiler to examine the exact query that is being executed from your C# project.

Comment: In your bottom query you have select **nome** instead of *name*, is that a typo? Also *password* vs **senha**.

Comment: @EvZ That aint a database related exception but a .net one. Probably due to not calling `.Read()` in the datareader before accesing its fields. Check styxs answer.

Comment: Did you expect to get more than one row by that query? You could simply use a JOIN instead of a IN with a subquery and use ExecuteScalar. Also don't catch exceptions just for the fun to rethrow them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call while `dr.Read();` like this:

```
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    dr.Read();
    usr.Name = dr["name"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Havent worked with npgsql, but in other databases after working with IDataReaders `.Close()` should be called. Looks like another problem.

Comment: @bradbury9 no need to close `NpgsqlConnection`  because he used `using(NpgsqlConnection ... )`

Comment: `dr.HasRows` is quite useless here, as `dr.Read()` already returns whether a row is available or now...

Comment: I was refering to close the Datareader, the `using(NpgsqlConnection ... )` would only close the connection is possible. But as long as the datareader is nor closed explicitly nor inside a `using (IDataReader dr = ...)` the connection would remain opened besides being inside the using.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `while` instead for checking `HasRows` followed by `.Read()` so the code would be like this:

```
while(dr.Read())
{
    usr.Name = dr["name"].ToString();
    // Assign rest of values if there any
}
```

Comment: I guess only one record is spected.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that when it is obvious there should only be one row.

Comment: @Crowcoder: If you are expecting only one row, then why don't you use `TOP 1`, I think there is no need to fetch `N` rows if you are expecting only one row

Comment: If you are setting the same variable over and over in a loop then that is a red flag, it would work here but next time OP writes a query it may bite him/her.